# TypeScript - Define type alias as subtype of another type alias?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, is it possible for a type alias to "*implement*" (or become subtype of) another type alias?

For example, I have the following type aliases ([TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)):

```js
type Predicate<TValue> = {
    op: "EQUAL" | "NOT_EQUAL",
    value: TValue,
}

type Predicates = Record<string, Predicate<string> | Predicate<boolean>>

/**
 * An implementation of the {@link Predicates} type.
 */
type AnimalPredicates = {
    species: Predicate<string>,
    isMammal: Predicate<boolean>,
}

// EXAMPLE:
const animalPredicates: AnimalPredicates = {
    species: { op: "EQUAL", value: "shiba_inu" },
    isMammal: { op: "EQUAL", value: true },
}

// `AnimalPredicates` is a subtype of `Predicates` so this is allowed
const animalPredicates2: Predicates = animalPredicates
```

The `AnimalPredicates` type alias is an implementation of the `Predicates` type (i.e. `AnimalPredicates` is subtype of `Predicates`).

Although I added a JSDoc comment saying that `AnimalPredicates` implements `Predicates`, it does not prevent me from doing something like:

```js
type AnimalPredicates = {
  // Predicate<number> is NOT allowed as record value in `Predicates`
  // But TS compiler does not complain...
  species: Predicate<number>,  
}
```

Is there a workaround to let the TS compiler know that `AnimalPredicates` must be a subtype of the `Predicate` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the type-level `satisfies`, it looks like this:

```
type Satisfies<I, T extends I> = T

type Predicates = Record<string, Predicate<string> | Predicate<boolean>>

type AnimalPredicates = Satisfies<Predicates, {
    species: Predicate<string>,
    isMammal: Predicate<boolean>,
}>

type NotPredicates = Satisfies<Predicates, {
    species: Predicate<string>,
    isMammal: string,
//     Type '{ species: Predicate<string>; isMammal: string; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'Predicates'.
//       Property 'isMammal' is incompatible with index signature.
//         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Predicate<string> | Predicate<boolean>'.(2344)
}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `AnimalPredicates` extend `Predicates`

```js
type Predicate<TValue> = {
    op: "EQUAL" | "NOT_EQUAL",
    value: TValue,
}

type Predicates = Record<string, Predicate<string> | Predicate<boolean>>

/**
 * An implementation of the {@link Predicates} type.
 */
interface AnimalPredicates extends Predicates  {
    species: Predicate<string>,
    isMammal: Predicate<boolean>,
}

// EXAMPLE:
const animalPredicates: AnimalPredicates = {
    species: { op: "EQUAL", value: "shiba_inu" },
    isMammal: { op: "EQUAL", value: true },
}

// `AnimalPredicates` is a subtype of `Predicates` so this is allowed
const animalPredicates2: Predicates = animalPredicates
```

see [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAJgSwMYENgQDwBUBq6ANgK4QB8UAvFAN4CwAUFC1APZgBcUARAKIBFAKoBBADI8oAH14A5APK4A+oNESANE1ZQAbsTLcC+iJsYBfJk1CRYCFBiwBnalABKEVGziJsj4HGQAOwBzdVskNEwcPwCQyhl4CIccACM2NiIIdEDycktGAHoAKiKtIqgRQKhkAFswTJqIQOBMZDYqtgAzKGAAC2haAAEiIIBrcPsoxzMe8AgAOjKCpiCsOE70VGhK2uJEyacoCAAPLEDEZ33Iw7otVkdIVGQIR24r5N9-IODyU21kRwAWXQNRqxDedmuqXSmWyvyYFkYTAKBSgfAAGiJATAxHxOExPIE-FBsrsiO8ptwdmDyZDks4aAxmPdHs9XnR2FxeKpxDwwnpSBBuDxHL1kCl0EogiRJGY-qwAcDQeCORxhTyNLpjNx-GQoHKEfkUVAAAbUvZ0qYm6rOdBQRwkFLWaBdU0UpzWxxsHpi5wAklEIhsADuSAJ7WJpJp7peACYIUkpi4oxbE04gA)

you can also clean it a bit by restricting the generic itself

```js
type Predicate<TValue extends string | boolean> = {
    op: "EQUAL" | "NOT_EQUAL",
    value: TValue,
}
/**
 * An implementation of the {@link Predicates} type.
 */
interface AnimalPredicates   {
    species: Predicate<string>,
    isMammal: Predicate<boolean>,
}

// EXAMPLE:
const animalPredicates: AnimalPredicates = {
    species: { op: "EQUAL", value: "shiba_inu" },
    isMammal: { op: "EQUAL", value: true },
}
```

see [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAJgSwMYENgQDwBUBq6ANgK7QQAeWAdogM5R3BzLUDmUAPlAEYD2fIhHTUAfFAC8UAN4BYAFBQlUPmABcUAEQBRAIoBVAIIAZTVy0A5APK4A+nqOmANAuVQAbsTIaCXiC-kAXwUAegAqMNcwqENqKGQAWzAhBIhqYExkPji+ADMoYAALaGkAASJWAGtYBBQMLDpAgvAIADookIVWLDhc9FRoWMTieCQ0TAgGJTlFZTpIVGRJjVG6iewmFnZRALdkOgBZdASE4hXa8axsfkFhMQDg+VCQqG0ADUMDmGNtNQVUbJMKAiYZEVaXZYxaig8H1SaSGSuOYLJZ0DTSFTqLQOEyaJwePwaTR0QrIHjoWysEhmQK7ZT7I4nM4yTFEnHOAmkCAaZhkKC0hSBIA)

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know we can define an interface that extends a type alias

Comment: Thanks. if this answers you question, please mark is as answer for future visitors

Comment: The first example is likely to be unwanted because it **keeps index signature** so you can add `hasBar: { op: "EQUAL", value: true }` @AnsonH

Comment: Thanks @Dimava! I. just copied the OP code without refactoring in the first one

Comment: @AnsonH and second example would not be fine if you have other types with `Predicate<number>`. Are you sure this answers your question?

Comment: @Dimava sorry I overlooked the limitation of this solution. Your solution can prevent undesired properties :)